# How do I write a hello world plugin for Protege 5?

Tags: plugins, protege

I need to learn how to write plugins for Protege Desktop version 5. But I don't find any information online.

All open source examples are

- a) already on plugin list in Protege 5 (these are not good examples of how to make new plugins)
- b) are complicated (need to make reverse-engineering to understand and no guarantee 
  that I'd be able to get it right).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the protégé wiki at http://protege.stanford.edu it has instructions and examples. Once you have the architecture existing plugins are easy to understand.